# Error %%writefile not found when try to modified txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

I got this error message:

UsageError: Line magic function `%%writefile` not found.

Please check my code and service log from jupyter notebook. Please help me.\

Version : Python 3.11.3
Environemt : Code-Server Docker Container (Ubuntu 20.04 Jammy).

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

I already tried to restart the kernel, re-run Jupyter Notebook, and re-install Ipykernel. But all of that doesn't make any difference. Still, I'm not able to try to modify my text file.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cell magic fuction` i.e `%%` must be on the first line where you have the comment. You don't have it on top so it was parsed as `Line magic function %%writefile not found.` i.e. `%`.

###### works:

`Cell magic fuction` on first line.

```
%%writefile file.txt
hello
```

**or**
`Cell magic fuction` on second line where the first line is empty.

```
%%writefile file.txt
hello
```

###### doesn't work:

comments or any other line on top

```
# some thing
%%writefile file.txt
hello
```

###### for your case:

removing comment works fine

```
%%writefile ../notes/perform-10.txt

test
```

Comment: @cevino just a reminder that you should accept the answer if it satisfies you.

Comment: I'm new in here, sure